# How can I reduce or otherwise influence the number of radial ticks in a polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I want a polar plot, but with a reduced number of radial (`r` dimension) ticks.  I already tried the suggested solutions from other questions, such as

```
pyplot.locator_params(axis='y', nticks=6)
```

but it did not seem to change anything.

I tried using `pyplot.gca().set_rticks([...])` but that requires to know the ticks in advance, while I am interested in just setting the maximum number of them.

What else could I try in order to reduce the number of ticks (or circles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may indeed use `ax.set_rticks()` to specify the specific ticklabels you want, e.g.

```
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])
```

as shown in [his example on the matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html).

In some cases this may be undesired and the usual locator parameters would be preferable. You can get the locator via `ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base` and set the parameters via `.set_params()`. Here you want to change the `nbins` parameter,

```
ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base.set_params(nbins=3)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(2)

ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base.set_params(nbins=3)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `ax.yaxis.get_major_locator().base.set_params(nbins=3)` was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: For a polar projection, we use `set_rticks()` (**r**) for the `r` axis, but `yaxis.get_major_locator()` (**y**), is the discrepancy intentional?